# TYPO3 8.7.16 Add custom Slider Content

Tags: php, plugins, typo3, element

I would like to create a custom content element on TYPO3 8.7.16 but all the guides i've seen so far, are either obsolete or some settings do not apply on the current TYPO3 Version. So for this example, if anyone could point me to the right direction, i would really appreciate it.

**The concept**

I would like to build a Slider:

- by choosing the images with FAL.
- with header
- with rich text

So far i have got this:

**TSConfig**

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.my_slider {
header = Slider
after = common
elements {
     my_slider {
         iconIdentifier = EXT:ak_extension_base/Resources/Public/Icon/Slider.svg
         title = Slider
         description = Create a Slider
         tt_content_defValues {
             CType = my_slider
         }
     }
 }
 show := addToList(my_slider)
}
```

**Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php**

(To make it visible on the list when it is selected)

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin(
array(
  'Slider',
  'my_slider',
  'EXT:ak_extension_base/Resources/Public/Icons/Slider.svg'
),
  'CType',
  'ak_extension_base'
);
```

On the same file i got the following code too:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['my_slider'] = array(
    'showitem' => '
       --div- -;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
         --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
         --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.headers;headers,
image;Slider_Image,
bodytext;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:bodytext_formlabel,
      --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance,
         --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.frames;frames,
         --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.appearanceLinks;appearanceLinks,
      --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:language,
         --palette--;;language,
      --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:access,
         --palette--;;hidden,
         --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,
      --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:categories,
         categories,
      --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:notes,
         rowDescription,
      --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:extended,
    ',
    'columnsOverrides' => [
  'bodytext' => [
     'config' => [
        'enableRichtext' => true,
        'richtextConfiguration' => 'default'
     ]
  ],
  'image' => [
     'label' => 'Slider Image',
    'config' => [
      'type' => 'inline',
   ],
],
]
    );
```

Everything works fine until now. I get the slider on its own tab, i get everything right.

1. Question: **How do i get to add images on columnsOverrides?**

**EDIT:** I have found the way to add images on TCA.

Now i want to create a template for this Content Element (Slider). I know i have to include a static file. So i did this:

**TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php**

```
<?php 
// Add an entry in the static template list found in sys_templates for static TS
 \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
 'ak_extension_base',
 'Configuration/TypoScript',
 'Include Slider'
 );
?>
```

With that, i am getting the static template on the list and i can include it.

Now i need to declare my fluid template so on the **typoscript** i have the following:

```
tt_content {
   my_slider < lib.contentElement
   my_slider {
      templateName = Slider
      dataProcessing {
         1 = Vendor\AkExtensionBase\DataProcessing\SliderProcessor
         1 {
            useHere = theConfigurationOfTheDataProcessor
         }
      }
   }
}
```

At first, i had this SliderProcessor as NewContentElementProcessor and as i added my content element, an error came up saying that the NewContentElementProcessor does not exist. So i corrected it and then, after that i had a **500 error**. So somewhere after this point i have something wrong configured. This is the rest of my code.

**TYPOSCRIPT**

```
lib.contentElement {
   templateRootPaths {
      200 = EXT:ak_extension_base/Resources/Private/Templates/
   }
}
```

**Classes/DataProcessing/SliderProcessor.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\AkExtensionBase\DataProcessing;

use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer;
use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\DataProcessorInterface;

class SliderProcessor implements DataProcessorInterface
{

   /**
    * Process data for the content element "My new content element"
    *
    * @param ContentObjectRenderer $cObj The data of the content element or page
    * @param array $contentObjectConfiguration The configuration of Content Object
    * @param array $processorConfiguration The configuration of this processor
    * @param array $processedData Key/value store of processed data (e.g. to be passed to a Fluid View)
    * @return array the processed data as key/value store
    */
   public function process(
      ContentObjectRenderer $cObj,
      array $contentObjectConfiguration,
      array $processorConfiguration,
      array $processedData
   )
   {
      $processedData['slider'] = 'This variable will be passed to Fluid';

      return $processedData;
   }
}
```

**Classes/Hooks/PageLayoutView/SliderPreviewRender.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\AkExtensionBase\Hooks\PageLayoutView;

use \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView;

class SliderPreviewRenderer implements PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface
{

   /**
    * Preprocesses the preview rendering of a content element of type "My new content element"
    *
    * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView $parentObject Calling parent object
    * @param bool $drawItem Whether to draw the item using the default functionality
    * @param string $headerContent Header content
    * @param string $itemContent Item content
    * @param array $row Record row of tt_content
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function preProcess(
      PageLayoutView &$parentObject,
      &$drawItem,
      &$headerContent,
      &$itemContent,
      array &$row
   )
   {
      if ($row['CType'] === 'my_slider') {
         $itemContent .= '<p>We can change our preview here!</p>';

         $drawItem = false;
      }
   }
}
```

**Resources/Private/Templates/Slider.html**

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<h1>{slider}</h1>
</html>
```

So any ideas what i am doing wrong? Is there any other way that i have not think of?

**EDIT** I can narrow my problem to the data processing. Somewhere along the way i messed up. For example, i have no clue what is the configuration of the data processor on the tt_content.

**EDIT 2** I have found the way to show everything on the FrontEnd.

Steps were taken to action following this documentation.
[Dokumentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/8.7/AddingYourOwnContentElements/)

Comment: Looks fine at the first glance. Did you replace your real namespaces with "Vendor\AkExtensionBase\" or is this really your Namespace? If it is like this, your extension should be located unter "typo3conf/ext/ak_extension_base" - correct? Did you clean the whole Cache and Autoload informations in the Installtool after adding your new classes?

Comment: I 've edited my question. I need more information about the data process and its connection to the fluid